# regex in javascript that read only one prefix$

Tags: javascript

I need validation that return valid price i.e $755.00 that is valid
$$755.00 is not valid $75 0.00 is not valid

I tried that way does not work. Please guide

```
validate(s) {
   var rgx = /^(?=.[0-9])(?=.[$,.])/ 
    return rgx.test(s);
  },
```

Thanks

Comment: Well if you want a regex, you will need to be more clear at what the options are. Only $ allowed? Values without decimals allowed, etc.? Regex101.com is great tool to help you. The following regex: `^.\d+.\d{2}` already works for the thing you specified, but you probably have to expend it. See my regex101 here: https://regex101.com/r/xtqZ2W/1/

Comment: $7$5 should return false but it returns true 755 should return true how to update ? and @555.00 should return false only accept $755.00 and 755.00

Comment: $7$5 doesn't return true on regex101? I updated the regex so it also matches 755: https://regex101.com/r/xtqZ2W/6

Comment: One last point that will help $7,111 or $75,666 or $75,144.00 should be acceptable

Comment: Well it got a whole lot more complex than, something like this? https://regex101.com/r/xtqZ2W/10